# core data 1 to many selection predicate

Tags: ios, core-data

I have two entities: class and student. each class can have many students, that is 1 to N reletionship.
class entity has two proerties : class name and toStudent;
student entity has two properties: student name and toClass;

How do I set the predicate so that I can get an array of classes which do not contain a specific student name. If the class does not have any student, it should also be in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below predicate

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SUBQUERY(toStudent, $student, $student.studentname == %@).@count == 0)",@"student_name_here"];
```